# html center align vertically not working

Tags: html, css

I am having this simple issue here, which worked before at a lot of places.
I am trying to align items inside a div vertically and at the center. Here in this code the margin-left works, but the margin top doesn't, I tried changing it to bigger values, still no effect at all.[image]

```css
.footer {
  background-color: #2E7FB6;
  color:white;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <section style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:10px;">FETCHED: {{ recordsFetched }} Work Order(s)</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the inline styling, use flexbox with `flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;` and `text-align center;` on the footer.

```css
.footer {
  background-color: #2E7FB6;
  color:white;
  height:50px;
  text-align: center;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <section>FETCHED: {{ recordsFetched }} Work Order(s)</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @rpm192 for the instant response.

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox tips just @rprm192 say. But if you want to make it more simple and support older browser, you can use `line-height`. Here's code for you

```
.footer {
  height: 50px;
}
.footer section {
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 50px; //make it same as height value
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bariq, I got it figured out, thanks anyways for joining in.